# How to do partially screen overlay in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I just finished the The App Brewery course, and found dribble.com when Angelica show it on her BMI Calculator course section for inspiration. Now I finished the course and find something in dribble for inspiration, then I found this one on, https://dribbble.com/shots/6120171-Groceries-Shopping-App-Interaction.

My question is how to implement that partially overlaid cart screen, I mean what widget should I use to archive that?

Here is the demo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The structure looks as

`Column`

{

`Container`(items)(box decoration),

`Row`(cartItems)(**hide/show**),

`Column`(cardItems)

}